# When i set req.session.whatever, the client doesn't get the cookie of connect.sid

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

I don't know what's wrong , but clearly when you use express-session ,and do something like that:

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var username = req.session.username ||'';
    res.render('index',{username:username});
});
app.post('/sign-up',function(req,res){
    users_controller.signUp(req,res);
    res.redirect('/');
})
app.post('/log-in',function(req,res){
    users_controller.logIn(req,res);
    res.redirect('/');
})};
```

and the users_controller.logIn function

```
exports.logIn = function(req,res){
User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).exec(function(err,user){
    if(!user){
        err = 'User Not Found';
    } else if (user.hashed_password===hashPW(req.body.password.toString())){
        req.session.user = user.id;
        req.session.username = user.username;
        req.session.msg = "success authenticated as " + user.username; 
        console.log(req.session);
    }else{
        err = "Wrong Password";
    }
    if(err){
        req.session.regenerate(function(){
            req.session.msg = err;
        });
    }
});
```

when i set req.session.whatever directly in my app.post('/log-in',callback),everything just works fine. But when I use the logIn function that was required from another file. Still,you can log req.session.whatever ,but the client side doesn't get the set-cookie from the response header.
I'm really in a mess .

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm stupid...

It's a async thing.
It redirects to homepage without finishing setting req.session.whatever.